# how to add array in hash table then append same as i go thru line by line

Tags: arrays, powershell, match

I have file with 80k lines. I want to read each line then look for group name which is between number and backup type ( incr,full or manual). then add group in hash table to corresponding server name. I want use hashtable which has array for group names. this is piece of requirement in my big script.

## Input file

```
rspedw03.corpads.local 3085876532 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 incr 02/23/2022 03/29/2022 03/29/2022  disk 1645592426 backup 3013 MB JCBDD2301P.CORPADS.LOCAL
rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2 JC_DB Clone_DR    full 02/23/2022 04/04/2022 04/04/2022         disk 1645592431 Clone_DR    997 KB MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2                   full 02/23/2022 04/04/2022 03/30/2022         disk 1645592431             997 KB JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
rsuedw03.corpads.local 12608 MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days MN_DB Clone_DR full 02/23/2022 04/21/2022 04/21/2022      disk 1645592432 Clone_DR     13 KB JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
'@ -split '\r?\n'
```

## output should look like

```
rspedw03.corpads.local  JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 JC_FS_DD2 UNIX_FS01_INCR_DD2 MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days MN_DB
rsuedw01.corpads.local  JC_DB_DB2 JC_DB Clone_DR
```

i got so far ,

```
$out = Get-Content C:\scripts\test1.txt 
$ht = @{} 
$arr = @() 

foreach ( $line in $out)
{ 
    $mn = $line -csplit "incr|full|manual"
    $md = $mn[0].split(" ")
}
```

#### but some line has one group other might have 4 group how do i capture that ?

Here is my complete code ,

```
$out=Get-Content C:\anil\scripts\test2.txt
$ht = @{}
$arr = @()
$today = Get-Date
foreach ( $line in $out){
              $arr=$line.Split(" ")
              if ( $arr[0] -ne "nwsppl300p.corpads.local"){
              $mn=$line -csplit "incr|full|manual"
              $md=$mn[1] -split "\s{1,}"
              if ($line -match  '.*( backup |Clone_DR ).*') {$btype=$md[9]} else {$btype=$md[8]}
              $clientHostName,$null,$backupPlans = -split $mn[0] 

              $date =$mn[1].split(" ")[2]
              $newdate=[Datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null)
              $diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $today -end $newdate
              #### look for one year only ########
              if ( $diff.Days -lt 400 ) {
                   if ( $arr[12] -ne "Clone_DR") {
                        if ($arr[0] -notin $ht.keys){
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]] = @{}
                                                                                                  
                                                 if ($btype -match "DB2") {  
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['Db2size'] = $arr[1]
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['groups'] = @($backupPlans)
                                                  }
                                                 if ($btype -match "RMAN") { 
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['RMANsize'] = $arr[1]
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['groups'] = @($backupPlans)
                                                 } 
                                                 if  ($btype -notmatch "RMAN" -and $btype -notmatch "DB2" ){
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize'] = $arr[1]
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['groups'] = @($backupPlans)
                                                 }
                                                 
                                                 } else {
                                                         
                                                if ($btype -match "DB2" -and $arr[1] -gt $ht[$arr[0]]['Db2size'] ) {
                                                $ht[$arr[0]]['Db2size'] = $arr[1]
                                                if ($backupplans -notin $ht[$arr[0]]['groups']) { $ht[$arr[0]]['groups'] += @($backupPlans)}
                                                }                                                                      
                                                if ($btype -match "RMAN" -and $arr[1] -gt $ht[$arr[0]]['RMANsize']) {
                                                
                                                $ht[$arr[0]]['RMANsize'] = $arr[1]
                                                if ($backupplans -notin $ht[$arr[0]]['groups']) { $ht[$arr[0]]['groups'] += @($backupPlans)}
                                                  } 
                                                if  ($btype -notmatch "RMAN" -and $btype -notmatch "DB2" -and $arr[1] -gt $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize']){ 
                                                 $ht[$arr[0]]['Filesize'] = $arr[1]
                                                 if ($backupplans -notin $ht[$arr[0]]['groups']) { $ht[$arr[0]]['groups'] += @($backupPlans)}
                                                 }

                                                    }
                                                    }  ###clone_dr
                                                    }   ###less than 400
                          } ### chcking for networker server
                          } #### looping thru file
write-host "=================================In MB ==============================================="
write-host "===ServerName==============OverAllsize======DB2size===========RMANsize========FileSize"
write-host "======================================================================================"

 $ht.GetEnumerator()| ForEach-Object  {
 $total = $_.value.Db2size/1024/1024 + $_.value.RMANsize/1024/1024 + $_.value.Filesize/1024/1024

 "{0,-25}     {1:n2}          {2:n2}            {3:n2}            {4:n2}   {5,-25}" -f $_.name,$total,$($_.value.Db2size/1024/1024),$($_.value.RMANsize/1024/1024),$($_.value.Filesize/1024/1024),$_.value.groups}
```

Comment: Okay, sounds pretty reasonable. What's currently stopping you? Having trouble reading the file? Parsing it? Adding new items to an existing array stored in a hashtable? Creating the hashtable itself?

Comment: i got so far , $out=Get-Content C:\scripts\test1.txt
$ht = @{}
$arr = @()

foreach ( $line in $out){
              
              $mn=$line -csplit "incr|full|manual"
              $md=$mn[0].split( " ")
                       } ### but some line has one group other might have 4 group how do i capture that ?

Comment: Please [edit these details into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71650464/edit) :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the part before the type (eg. `'rsuedw01.corpads.local 1020344 JC_DB_DB2  '`) split into individual words (`'rsuedw01.corpads.local', '1020344', 'JC_DB_DB2'`), then you know that the first string is going to be the hostname, the second string is going to be the ignored, and anything else is necessarily a label you want to collect.

Then you just need to ensure that an entry with an associated array exists:

```
$backupLogLines = @(Get-Content C:\scripts\test1.txt) -match "incr|full|manual"
$planTable = @{}

foreach ($line in $backupLogLines)
{
    $metadataParts = $line -csplit "incr|full|manual"

    # first string is host name, 
    # second string is discarded, 
    # ... and the rest are backup plans
    $clientHostName,$null,$backupPlans = -split $metadataParts[0]    

    if(-not $planTable.Contains($clientHostName)){
        # Create new array containing the backup plans for the current
        $planTable[$clientHostName] = @($backupPlans)
    }
    else {
        $planTable[$clientHostName] += $backupPlans
    }
}
```

To write the results to a file:

```
$planTable.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Name,$(@($_.Value |Sort-Object -Unique) -join ' ') -join '  '
} |Set-Content path\to\output.txt
```

Comment: will above code  $planTable[$clientHostName] += $backupPlans  , will not have duplicates ??

Comment: i have pasted entire code here, can you look why its not getting backupPlans populated in hashtable then not able to print out.

Comment: @postmaster420 I modified the last snippet to remove duplicate values

Comment: is there way to add only those backuplans which not in array since there will be thousands of entry ? i want to add if that backupplan is not in array.

Comment: @postmaster420 in that case it'd be better (and _much_ faster) to use a hashset instead, I'll write up an example later (on my phone right now)

Comment: Hi Mathias , did you get chance to create example code ?